# Fragment Replace not working when list onclick occurs

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a veiwpager that utilises fragments for its pages and within one of the tabs i have a dualpane style setup where one fragment is a list fragment and the other a details fragment, everything works fine as far as updating the details fragment when a list item is clicked.

But im trying now to replace the list fragment with another on list item click but i cannot get it to work no matter what i try, none of the fragments are hardcoded and the list fragment itself is added via a childfragmentManager to meet the nested fragment requirements, but it doesn't seem to matter what i try to replace the list fragment with another i always get an error, or when trying to manually remove then add, the remove will work but not the add.

the error message doesnt seem helpful, to me at least, but heres an example

```
06-03 01:49:04.707: E/AndroidRuntime(1431): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 01:49:04.707: E/AndroidRuntime(1431): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-03 01:49:04.707: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:651)
06-03 01:49:04.707: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
06-03 01:49:04.707: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
06-03 01:49:04.707: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-03 01:49:04.707: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-03 01:49:04.707: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-03 01:49:04.707: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-03 01:49:04.707: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 01:49:04.707: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-03 01:49:04.707: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-03 01:49:04.707: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-03 01:49:04.707: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

if anyone has any ideas on a solution that be great!

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my issue myself, i was making a reference to the backstack for another purpose in the fragment i was replacing my initial list with, i had completely forgot about this reference as using that fragment as the replacement was ment to be temporary, newbie error.